# Custom Fields isn't Working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I've created an hours of operation widget in the sidebar. It's not outputting the values that are set within the Home page template. This is located in the sidebar include file. Could that be affecting it?

```
<div class="widget" id="hours">
    <?php $hours = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hours', false); ?>
    <div class="widget-title">Business Hours:</div>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($hours as $hour) {
            echo '<li>'.$hour.'</li>';
          } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

--

**UPDATE:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 column">
        <div class="slider"><?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=4]"); ?></div>
      </div>
   </div> 

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-9 column"> 
            <article>
                    <h3 class="section-title">What's On</h3>

                      <?php query_posts ('posts_per_page=3'); ?>
                      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                     <section>
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                                <div class="large-4 column"> 
                                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?>
                                    </a>
                                  <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>

                            <div class="large-8 column"> 
                                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                    <div class="post-details">
                                    <p class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                                    <p class="meta" id="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p> 
                                    <p class="entry"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </div><!--row-->
                     </section>

                    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

           </article>
        </div>

        <div class="large-3 hide-for-small column"> 
           <aside>
              <?php include('sidebar-home.php'); ?>
           </aside>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 column">
            <div id="weekly-promotions">
                <p class="extra hide-for-small">Every week we hand select our favourite finds.</p>
                <h3 class="section-title">Weekly Promotions</h3> 
               <?php echo do_shortcode("[supercarousel id=26]"); ?>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

**SIDEBAR CONTENTS:**

```
<h3 class="section-title">Find Us</h3>
<div class="widget" id="hours">
<?php wp_reset_query();
global $post;
$hours = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hours', false); ?>
<div class="widget-title">Business Hours:</div>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($hours as $hour) {
            echo '<li>'.$hour.'</li>';
          } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($hours); echo '</pre><br />'; echo $post->ID; ?>
<div class="widget" id="directions">
<div class="widget-title">Directions:</div>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2878.098955645896!2d-79.05700300000001!3d43.833046099999954!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89d4de53bb478629%3A0x23b9414d4c475d10!2s1400+Squires+Beach+Rd!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1394214160873" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>      
</div>
<div class="widget" id="map">
    <div class="widget-title">Download Our<br /> Floor Map!</div>                              
</div>
```

Comment: Natasha, set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in your `wp-config.php` file and test again. If there is uninitialized variable (my suspect is `$post->ID`) - this information will be displayed on page and in general develop your themes with setting set to `true`, you'll see a bunch of other useful info also. This way will be *much* easier to see the root of the problem.

Comment: @bodi0 Thanks! I've updated WP_DEBUG to true and I'm not receiving any error anywhere.

Comment: Where exactly this `post_meta` is being set? Which post/page/cpt contains this meta? Only one? All? I suspect this `global $post` is not what you think it is...

Comment: the `post_meta` is located in the sidebar include file which attached to the index.php file. The values are being pulled from the home page template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to specify that it was pulling from a page not a post:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page'); ?>
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $hours = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hours', false); ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($hours as $hour) {
                echo '<li>'.$hour.'</li>';
            } ?>
        </ul>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that a sidebar widget query has affected the post data and not reset it back to the main query. To be sure you're accessing the correct post's meta perform a reset and get the global. Example below:

```
<div class="widget" id="hours">
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    global $post;
    $hours = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hours', false); ?>
    <div class="widget-title">Business Hours:</div>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($hours as $hour) {
            echo '<li>'.$hour.'</li>';
          } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm okay, let's try something else. Are you getting any output? Add the following and let me know the result. `<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($hours); echo '</pre><br />'; echo $post->ID; ?>` Make sure to do this after you've set hours using get_post_meta.

Comment: It is saying this: `Array
(
)

44`

Comment: OK can you check if 44 is the ID of your homepage? Go to Pages in the admin and check it in the URL

Comment: Nope. It is 52. So the fact that it's in the include sidebar must be causing the conflict, right?

Comment: Yep something is altering the query so when you access the post global you're getting the wrong ID. Can you try replacing wp_reset_postdata() with wp_reset_query(). Failing that can you update your question with the contents of your homepage template?